# Select and GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with the following fields

```
ID
fk_siteID
VisitDate
```

I want to write a query with LINQ that returns me the number of records in a day with a specific `SiteID`. For example if `siteid=1` show me

```
12.1.2014   6
13.1.204    8
```

I wrote this query

```
 var n = from a in db.CompanyWebsiteUsers
         group a by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.VisitDate) into g
         orderby g.FirstOrDefault().VisitDate
         where  g.FirstOrDefault().fk_siteID == WebsiteID
         select new
         {
             key = g.Key,
             dayofweek = SqlFunctions.DateName("weekday", g.Key),
             count = g.Count()
         };
grdDailyRes.DataSource = n;
grdDailyRes.DataBind();
```

The result that show me this query:
when 2 record is in my table that `VisitDate` field's of these record are same one of them with `siteid=1` and second `siteid=2`.
If `websiteid` is 1 or is 2 this query count first of them.

Answer (score 1):

You only check the first item in a group, but you have to check the other items as well. The simplest solution is to move the where statement, i.e.

```
var n = from a in db.CompanyWebsiteUsers
                    where  a.fk_siteID == WebsiteID
                    group a by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.VisitDate) into g
                    orderby g.FirstOrDefault().VisitDate
                    select new
```